# kendo-dropdownlist - Clears the filter value when hiding the dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

I am using kendo-angular-dropdowns 2.1.0 .And Added [popupSettings] property . and it works as expected in IE11 also. However, clear filter value is not working.

Lets say if i enter some value (xyz) to search and close the modal. And when open again...the value remains in search textbox.

expected behavior : Clears the filter value when hiding the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a bug and it is already fix in `dev`.
I successfully reproduce you problem on [official demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/filtering/).

However on [development page](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/filtering/), this is fixed.

You can check this with your code using [development build](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/development-builds/).